# Powershell build solution using devenv.exe taking much time

Tags: powershell

I am using the following code to build some projects using PowerShell but this is taking nearly 30 minutes of time and some times it is taking more than that too, here is the PowerShell script I had when I execute it locally it is getting build in

```
$sourceDirectory = "D:\Service"
$SolutionToBuild = @("Solution1.sln","Solution2.sln","Solution3.sln","Solution4.sln")

$projectFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "$sourceDirectory" -Filter *.sln -Recurse


foreach($solution in $SolutionToBuild)
{
     foreach($projectFile in $projectFiles)
    {
           if($projectFile.Name -eq $solution)
           {
                 write-host $projectFile.Name;
                 $SlnFilePath = $projectFile.FullName
                 $BuildParameters = """$SlnFilePath"" /Build Release|x86"
                 $CleanParameters = """$SlnFilePath"" /Clean Release|x86"
                 Start-Process -FilePath $vsPath -ArgumentList $CleanParameters -Wait
                 Start-Process -FilePath $vsPath -ArgumentList $BuildParameters -Wait
                 break;
           }
     }
}
```

So can one let me know why this taking much time

Comment: You can add timings to narrow down the line(s) that's taking a lot of time. Assuming it's the build itself, how long does it take using VS and how long does it taken using Powershell?

Comment: use the `Measure-command` for the powershell to check the time of the PS. This will help in segregating and narrowing down the time consumption

Answer (score 1):

A minor change to the code will affect the total performance. Instead of using Start-Process, you may use the following code:

```
 $buildProcInfo = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo -ArgumentList "devenv.exe", $buildArgs
 try { $buildProcess = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($buildProcInfo) }
 catch {
          Write-Host "Error"
          # exit?
        }
 $buildProcess.WaitForExit()
```